# TryRetry - Try, Catch, then Retry

Tags: c#, error-handling, asynchronous

I have created a class to try, catch and retry N times. My class also supports retrying asynchronously. I'm wondering if there are better ways to implement this. I'm most concerned with the `HandleException` and `RetryLoop` methods, but also about the design of the class as a whole. [TryRetry GitHub](https://github.com/cpamp21/TryRetry)

```
/// <summary>
/// Class for simulating Try, Catch, Retry (n) times.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TResult">Type to be returned.</typeparam>
public static class TryRetry<TResult>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Handles exceptions thrown
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">The <see cref="Exception"/> thrown.</param>
    /// <param name="exCatch"><see cref="IDictionary{TKey, TValue}"/> containing expected <see cref="Exception"/> <see cref="Type"/> 
    /// as key and <see cref="Func{TResult}"/> to invoke for that <see cref="Exception"/> as value.</param>
    /// <returns>Result of catch function.</returns>
    private static TResult HandleException(Exception e, IDictionary<Type, Func<TResult>> exCatch)
    {
        TResult result = default(TResult);
        bool handled = false;

        foreach (var ec in exCatch)
        {
            if (e.GetType() == ec.Key)
            {
                if (ec.Value != null) { result = ec.Value.Invoke(); }
                handled = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!handled) throw e;
        return result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Try, catch, then retry (n) times until max tries reached, an unexpected exception is thrown, 
    /// or try block executes without an exception.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="tryFunc">Try code block to execute.</param>
    /// <param name="exCatch"><see cref="IDictionary{TKey, TValue}"/> containing expected <see cref="Exception"/> <see cref="Type"/> 
    /// as key and <see cref="Func{TResult}"/> to invoke for that <see cref="Exception"/> as value.</param>
    /// <param name="maxTries">Maximum number of times to retry, minimum once.</param>
    /// <param name="millisecondsDelay">Milliseconds to delay next try.</param>
    /// <returns>tryFunc return value or catchFunc return value.</returns>
    private static TResult RetryLoop(Func<TResult> tryFunc, IDictionary<Type, Func<TResult>> exCatch,
        int maxTries = 1, int millisecondsDelay = 0)
    {
        TResult result = default(TResult);
        int numTries = 0;
        maxTries = maxTries < 0 ? 1 : maxTries;

        while (numTries <= maxTries)
        {
            try
            {
                result = tryFunc();
                break;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                result = HandleException(e, exCatch);
            }
            finally
            {
                numTries++;
                if (millisecondsDelay > 0 && numTries <= maxTries)
                {
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(millisecondsDelay);
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Try, catch, then retry (n) times until max tries reached, an unexpected exception is thrown, 
    /// or try block executes without an exception.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TException">Expected <see cref="Exception"/> to handle.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="tryFunc">Try code block to execute.</param>
    /// <param name="catchFunc">Catch code block to execute.</param>
    /// <param name="maxTries">Maximum number of times to retry, minimum once.</param>
    /// <param name="millisecondsDelay">Milliseconds to delay next try.</param>
    /// <returns>tryFunc return value or catchFunc return value.</returns>
    public static TResult Retry<TException>(Func<TResult> tryFunc, Func<TResult> catchFunc = null,
        int maxTries = 1, int millisecondsDelay = 0) where TException : Exception, new()
    {
        return RetryLoop(
            tryFunc,
            new Dictionary<Type, Func<TResult>>(){ { new TException().GetType(), catchFunc } },
            maxTries,
            millisecondsDelay);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Try, catch, then retry (n) times until max tries reached, an unexpected exception is thrown, 
    /// or try block executes without an exception.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="tryFunc">Try code block to execute.</param>
    /// <param name="exCatch"><see cref="IDictionary{TKey, TValue}"/> containing expected <see cref="Exception"/> <see cref="Type"/> 
    /// as key and <see cref="Func{TResult}"/> to invoke for that <see cref="Exception"/> as value.</param>
    /// <param name="maxTries">Maximum number of times to retry, minimum once.</param>
    /// <param name="millisecondsDelay">Milliseconds to delay next try.</param>
    /// <returns>tryFunc return value or catchFunc return value.</returns>
    public static TResult Retry(Func<TResult> tryFunc, IDictionary<Type, Func<TResult>> exCatch,
        int maxTries = 1, int millisecondsDelay = 0)
    {
        return RetryLoop(tryFunc, exCatch, maxTries, millisecondsDelay);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Try, catch, then retry (n) times asynchronously until max tries reached, an unexpected exception is thrown, 
    /// or try block executes without an exception.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="tryFunc">Try code block to execute.</param>
    /// <param name="catchFunc">Catch code block to execute.</param>
    /// <param name="maxTries">Maximum number of times to retry, minimum once.</param>
    /// <param name="millisecondsDelay">Milliseconds to delay next try.</param>
    /// <returns>Task</returns>
    public static async Task<TResult> RetryAsync<TException>(Func<TResult> tryFunc, Func<TResult> catchFunc = null,
        int maxTries = 1, int millisecondsDelay = 0) where TException : Exception, new()
    {
        return await Task.Run(() => RetryLoop(
            tryFunc,
            new Dictionary<Type, Func<TResult>>() { { new TException().GetType(), catchFunc } },
            maxTries,
            millisecondsDelay));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Try, catch, then retry (n) times asynchronously until max tries reached, an unexpected exception is thrown, 
    /// or try block executes without an exception.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="tryFunc">Try code block to execute.</param>
    /// <param name="exCatch"><see cref="IDictionary{TKey, TValue}"/> containing expected <see cref="Exception"/> <see cref="Type"/> 
    /// as key and <see cref="Func{TResult}"/> to invoke for that <see cref="Exception"/> as value.</param>
    /// <param name="maxTries">Maximum number of times to retry, minimum once.</param>
    /// <param name="millisecondsDelay">Milliseconds to delay next try.</param>
    /// <returns>Task</returns>
    public static async Task<TResult> RetryAsync(Func<TResult> tryFunc, IDictionary<Type, Func<TResult>> exCatch,
        int maxTries = 1, int millisecondsDelay = 0)
    {
        return await Task.Run(() => RetryLoop(tryFunc, exCatch, maxTries, millisecondsDelay));
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to research the *circuit breaker pattern* for solving the "retry n times" problem in an object oriented way.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Very interesting, I like it. This looks like something I will most likely implement. Thanks!

Comment: My standard caution for this pattern: it does not handle composition well. If method A retries ten times before throwing, and method B calls method A and *it* retries ten times before throwing, and method C calls method B and *it* retries ten times before throwing, then we actually try operation A a thousand times.  If A introduces a delay then the user could be waiting minutes or hours.  Retry logic is one of those things that requires global understanding; either B needs to understand that A has already been retried, or it needs to not retry A.

Comment: @EricLippert I have been thinking about this and I might leave it up to the developer. The only solution I could come up with was to have a parameter of a unique id for that Retry call.

Comment: @Clint: As a colleague of mine used to say "every time we let a developer write a line of code, that's one more opportunity for a bug".  Personally I am not a big fan of retry logic; most of the time, if something failed once it will fail again. There are of course exceptions. The last time I wrote retry logic it was for attempting to close a file and then re-open it again; badly-written virus checkers will not wait for a possible re-open before locking the file to examine it to see if I just wrote a virus into it, so the close-reopen pattern needs a retry.  Vexing!

Comment: @EricLippert That is true, but wouldn't it be worse to offer a poor solution rather than leave it to the developer? I see why you're not a fan of retry logic, I just read your blog post on the four types of exceptions and it seems retry is unnecessary outside of trying to connect to a service. I may need to think about this problem some more.

Comment: @Clint: Like all design problems, there are going to be tradeoffs, and you're going to have to think about what the developer really needs to solve the particular problem. Maybe they need straight-up retry logic. Maybe they actually need a robust, carefully-designed framework for describing and implementing a coordinated, cross-component approach to failure management. The latter is a lot harder to write, but if it's what is actually needed, then spend some time designing that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see 2 little issues with `RetryLoop` method.

First, you check `maxTries` for an invalid negative value but I think that a 0 value is equally invalid.  So I would suggest this change:

`maxTries = maxTries <= 0 ? 1 : maxTries;`

Or equally you could use:

`maxTries = Max(maxTries, 1);`

The other things is when you break out of the `while` loop thanks to not having an exception, the `finally` block still executes, which means you have to wait up to `millisecondsDelay` once more than needed.

I would suggest this change:

```
try
{
    result = tryFunc();
    numTries = maxTries;
    break;
}
```

Then there is no delay in the `finally` block!

Comment: Nice catches! I like your `Math.Max()` solution, it's much easier to read. For the finally block, I think I would rather pull the code out and put it at the end of the loop. Thank you for your input!